# jQuery Ajax Codebehind Post is "OK" but doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I try to call a function in ASP.NET via jQuery Ajax like this:

```
var params = "{'name':" + "\"" + name + "\"}";
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CreateTopic.aspx/CreateNewTopic",
            data: params,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {

            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("Failed to send : " + response);
            }
        });
```

i get [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error].

If i do it like this:

```
        var params = "{'name':" + "\"" + name + "\"}";
        $.post("CreateTopic.aspx/CreateNewTopic", params);
```

I get: [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]

But the debugging point i put in here:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static object CreateNewTopic(string name)
    {
        return PrivateTopic.createNewTopic(name, 1);
    }
```

is not reached.

Comment: The only difference appears to be the data formats sent and requested. I expect Post will not be sending/requesting JSON by default. As I only use WebAPI nowadays, I can't comment on the changes you would need for an ASPX.

Answer (score 0):

You will not believe it but the answer is:

Change the target framework to .NET 4.0

This code works:

```
            var params = "{'name':" + "\"" + name + "\"}";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CreateTopic.aspx/CreateNewTopic",
            data: params,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Topic " + name + " wurde erfolgreich gespeichert.");
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("Failed to send : " + response);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

your data property should be {'name':" + "\"" + name + "\"} 
not "{'name':" + "\"" + name + "\"}", the former is an object while the latter is a string that is invalid as a query parameter. 
Better yet, just try below lines instead of using 'params' variable.

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CreateTopic.aspx/CreateNewTopic",
        data: {'name':" + "\"" + name + "\"},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {

        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert("Failed to send : " + response);
        }
    });
```